# ¿Cómo no ejecutar un código cuando se cumple una condición?

Tags: vb

Soy nuevo en VB, pero tengo un problema, necesito hacer un if que cuando se cumpla, comente partes de código para que no se ejecute. 
Mi pregunta es si hay algún método que lo haga u otro que haga que se comente.

¿O se puede evaluar una linea y comentar?

Comment: Bueno, realmente para eso existen los condicionales, para hacer algo o no cuando se cumple o no una condición. En este caso, simplemente sería tal y como lo describes: **No ejecutar cierto código cuando se cumple una condición.**

Comment: Efectivamente, lo que dice @Shaz es correcto, las condicionales son para ejecutar ciertas cosas. Ahora, si la consulta es que deje de ejecutar para volver volver a validar o simplemente salir del evento que estas ejecutando, puedes agregar la línea de código "return;".

Comment: Gracias, resolvieron mi duda sobre las condiciones. Solo una cosa mas, existe una instrucción que comente una linea de código o la descomente en vb?

Comment: No me suena que se pueda Comentar/desconectar una línea de código en tiempo de ejecución. Si acaso, si no quieres ejecutar algo, lo que haces es poner la condición NEGADA

Answer (score 2):

Si lo que quieres es que se excluya el código, esa es la función de los condicionales, como ya lo han mencionado.

```vb
If True Then
   MsgbBox "Código que se ejecutará"
Else
   MsgbBox "Código que no se ejecutará"
End If
```

Otra cosa que puedes hacer es separar tu código en Subrutinas o Funciones, de esa manera puedes tener el código sin que se ejecute y controlarlo con `If ... Else`.

```vb
' No se ejecutará Mostrar_Mensaje hasta el momento en que se llame
Sub Mostrar_Mensaje(Mensaje As String)
   MsgBox Mensaje
End Sub

' No se ejecutará Entrada_Datos hasta el momento en que se llame
Function Entrada_Datos(Mensaje As String) As String
   Entrada_Datos = InputBox(Mensaje)
End Function

Dim NuevoMensaje As String

NuevoMensaje = "Saludos"

If True Then
   NuevoMensaje = Entrada_Datos("Teclea un mensaje")
End If

Call Mostrar_Mensaje(NuevoMensaje)
```

Tal vez si explicas mejor lo que quieres lograr se te pueda apoyar a reformular tu pregunta